# If I use "registerDefaults" to register defaults, I can not remove the defaults which I registered

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

```
NSDictionary *dictionnary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"content", @"myKey", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionnary];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"myKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myKey"]);
```

Log :

```
2012-12-17 17:09:05.062 browserHD[4075:c07] content
```

Why the result value "content"? I want the result value "nil".

Comment: Or can I change the value which I registered?

Comment: check my code and please update me

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct...

This may not be the perfect solution,. but a little bit of tweak to solve the problem.

If you use this way it works !!!

```
- (IBAction)set:(id)sender {
    NSMutableDictionary *aDict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
    [aDict setObject:_myText.stringValue forKey:@"key"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:aDict];
}

- (IBAction)remove:(id)sender {
    NSMutableDictionary *aDict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
    [aDict setObject:@"null" forKey:@"key"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:aDict];
}

- (IBAction)get:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"-> %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"key"]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.I know if i use "setObject:",it can be work.But the problem is i must use "registerDefaults:".

Answer (score 0):

The registerDefaults affects a different "level" of user defaults than the setObject:forKey: or the removeObjectForKey. It goes into the global user defaults which is a level higher than the standard user defaults. "Global" being a misnomer because it is still local to your app.

You cannot remove values from the global user defaults with this method.

`Global Defaults (NSGlobalDomain)
 -> User Defaults (NSRegistrationDomain)`

If a value is in user values then it overrides the global value. If not then the value from Global Defaults is taken. Adding and removing values only affects the User Defaults level.

Apparently you cannot get rid of the global defaults because if you remove the user default the global one will always "shine through". But you could set the object value for something you want to "replace with nil" to `[NSNull null]`. Then in your code you'd check for this case: either the default is nil or it is `[NSNull null]` which would tell you that the value is not set.

Comment: I use resetStandardUserDefaults to resets but the defaults still exist.